# Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(255) Using Always Encrypted with Secure Enclaves and CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, encryption, always-encrypted

I'm trying to return an Encrypted value from the database from within a Case Statement.

```
DECLARE @emptyValue VARCHAR(255) = '';
Select Top 1 CASE WHEN o.shippingFirstName = @emptyValue AND o.shippingLastName = @emptyValue  

THEN '' ELSE o.shippingFirstName  END AS nameDisplay  from [Order] o
```

When I run it, I get the following Error

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'cfg_phoenix_prod') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'
> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'cfg_phoenix_prod') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'
> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'cfg_phoenix_prod') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'
> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'cfg_phoenix_prod') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'
> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'cfg_phoenix_prod') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 17]
> Statement(s) could not be prepared.
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 17]
> Statement(s) could not be prepared.
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 17]
> Statement(s) could not be prepared.
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 17]
> Statement(s) could not be prepared.
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 17]
> Statement(s) could not be prepared.
> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Internal error. Metadata for parameter '@pc2d5b410384a4500b3493a0306f71d28' in statement or procedure 'DECLARE @emptyValue AS VARCHAR (255) = @pc2d5b410384a4500b3493a0306f71d28;

SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN o.shippingFirstName = @emptyValue
AND o.shippingLastName = @emptyValue THEN ' ' ELSE o.shippingFirstName END AS nameDisplay
FROM   [Order] AS o;

' is missing in resultset returned by sp_describe_parameter_encryption.

The Comparison seems to work fine. It's only when the ELSE tries to return the o.shippingFirstName that generates the issue.

A Similar query such as this works fine:

```
DECLARE @emptyValue VARCHAR(255) = ''; 
Select Top 1 o.shippingFirstName   from [Order] o  where o.shippingFirstName is not Null and o.shippingFirstName <> @emptyValue
```

Is there something I'm missing or can it not be done?

Dazed and Confused

Comment: I haven't seen this before but did you try `THEN CONVERT(varchar(255), '')` or just `THEN @emptyValue`?

Comment: Side note: `CASE` **expression**, not statement. SQL knows no flow control statements at all.

Comment: @stickybit [Control-of-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/control-of-flow)? :)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: That's about the procedural part of T-SQL, *not* the declarative *SQL* part which the OP uses. I wrote SQL. In the SQL part there is no flow control, there's not even a flow.

Answer (score 1):

Because the columns are encrypted using Always Encrypted, the server cannot read them *at all*. Only the client can decrypt them. It cannot compare the column value to an unencrypted variable, they are simply incompatible. The only operations you could do are to compare the column with another encrypted value.

There is no way for it to compare them to anything. Instead, you would need to remove the declaration of the `@emptyValue` variable and pass it in as a parameter direct from the client.

And if you are using randomized encryption you can't even do this either, you would have to just return it to the client.

Comment: This is actually Always Encrypted with Secure Enclaves so I can perform some comparisons and even use the LIKE operator.

Comment: Hum, good point, missed that. Are you sure you are able to do normal comparisons, such as `CASE WHEN o.shippingFirstName = ''`